# Laravel Redirect::action outputs extra "index"

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using this code in a controller

```
Redirect::action('myController@getIndex')
```

and in routes.php

```
Route::controller('/my','myController');
```

I was expecting redirect to `/my` but this redirected to `/my/index` instead.

How can I fix the URL in this case.

P.S: Both URLs are ok and show same page, but I prefer the cleaner one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `::controller` routes the function name maps/plays a part in the url, so you would not be able to get around this easily using `::controller` based routes. Instead I would advise to make use of named routes like so:

```
Route::get('my', array('as' => 'my.index', 'uses' => 'MyController@getIndex'));
```

Then to redirect to this route:

```
Redirect::route('my.index');
```

See this [blog article post](http://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil) by Phil Sturgeon why using implicit routing is generally bad practise.